# How to use two substring() method in join condition in linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I'm implementing asp.net core project. I have a query like the following:

```
var numerator = from t1 in _context.Apiapplicant
                            join t2 in _context.ApiApplicantHistory on t1.Id equals t2.ApiApplicantId
                            join t3 in _context.EntityType on t2.LastReqStatus equals t3.Id
                            join t4 in mytotal on new { t2.Date.Substring(0,4), t2.Date.Substring(2,5) } equals new { t4.Year, t4.Month }
```

....

My problem is, in the last line I want to join on mytotal with the given condition, however the expression t2.Date.Substring(0,4), t2.Date.Substring(2,5) } equals new { t4.Year, t4.Month } ... has got error. I appreciate if anyone tells me how can I write such that condition.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a method  to create a member of anonymous object, you need to assign it to member Name, if not will give the error :

> *Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access*.

Change the last line to :

```
join t4 in mytotal on new { Year = t2.Date.Substring(0,4), Month = t2.Date.Substring(2,5) } equals new { t4.Year, t4.Month }
```

I hope you find this helpful.